# Getting HTTP Status 404 error when trying to run servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with my simple servlet that I am trying to run, Hello.java. I made it in eclipse, then placed the file it in the `webapps/ServletTest/WEB-INF/classes` folder and compiled it, creating the file `Hello.class` in the same folder. I then modified my web.xml file to map the servlet and tried to run it through the following address

```
http://localhost:8080/ServletTest/Hello
```

However, this did not work, giving the following error

**HTTP Status 404 -**

**type Status report**

**message**

**description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42**

The mapping in the web.xml file looks like this:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Main.Hello</servlet-class>
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The code of the servlet:

```
package Main;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/Hello")
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Hello() {
super();
 }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse                   

response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String path = request.getContextPath();
    String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    out.print("<html>" +
    "<title>Hello</title>" +
            "Hello World"+ "<br>" +
    "Your ip is: " + ip + "<br>" +
    "Your path is: " + path
    + "</html>");       
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   

throws     ServletException, IOException {

}

}
```

Comment: Why you are using both ways or url mapping ???

Comment: I tried removing the mapping from web.xml and it did not work. How do I use this mapping: @WebServlet("/Hello")?

Comment: @DarbininkaiBroliai You need to declare in your `web.xml` that your application is using Servlet 3.0.

Comment: Delimanolis is correct and stick to web.xml few days as you are new. That gives an strong understanding. :) A personal suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiled `Hello.class` file should be in the folder

```
webapps/ServletTest/WEB-INF/classes/Main
```

since it's declared to be in package `Main`.

Also, you can see Tomcat's startup logs in `/logs/catalina.out` or `/logs/catalina.log`, depending.

---

Also, Suresh is right in the comments, use either a `<servlet>` declaration or `@WebServlet`. Don't use both.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete web.xml.
Annotation `@WebServlet("/Hello")` is enough for Tomcat 7+

Comment: You can keep both. Just removing the entry from web.xml and using annotations will do.

Answer (score 1):

If the root folder not having proper permission you will face this issue. So please check the root folder property and remove read only permission and add user to full access permission in security tab.

Comment: This should be comment.

Comment: there was perission issue